# Android Reveal Animation to start an Activity

Tags: android, android-animation

how can I use Reveal Animation between two activities?? There's a lot of information and examples about how to use it to start a view inside an Activity, but I want to click a button and start a Reveal Animation to open the next Activity. 
I tried including the second layout inside the first one and setting it Invisible, and then reveal it when the button is clicked. But it doesn't work fine.  I'm wondering if I can simply define the Reveal animation as an XML, but I wouldn't know how to.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Reveal Effect successfully worked for me on activity and fragment too
Apply below code to set reveal effect on activity or fragment. Remove Comment to use specific animation form below code.

->Apply this code after setcontentview

```
                rootview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootview);
                rootview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                rootview.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                    v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

              /*//BOTTOM RIGHT TO TOP LEFT ANIMATION
                int cx = (framelayout.getLeft() + framelayout.getRight());
                int cy = (framelayout.getTop() + framelayout.getBottom());
                // get the hypothenuse so the radius is from one corner to the other
                int radius = (int) Math.hypot(right, bottom);
                Animator reveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, cx, cy, 0, radius);
                reveal.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                reveal.setDuration(600);
                reveal.start();*/

              /*  //LEFT TOP TO BOTTOM RIGHT ANIMATION
                int cx1 = 0;
                int cy1 = 0;
                // get the hypothenuse so the radius is from one corner to the other
                int radius1 = (int) Math.hypot(right, bottom);
                Animator reveal1 = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, cx1, cy1, 0, radius1);
                reveal1.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2f));
                reveal1.setDuration(1000);
                reveal1.start();*/

               /* //EFFECT START WITH CENTER
                float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
                int cx1 = (framelayout.getLeft() + framelayout.getRight()) / 2;
                int cy1 = (framelayout.getTop() + framelayout.getBottom()) / 2;
                Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, cx1, cy1, 0, finalRadius);
                anim.setDuration(1000);
                anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                anim.start();*/

                    //OPEN WITH BOTTOM CENTER
                    int cx = (rootview.getLeft() + rootview.getRight()) / 2;
                    int cy = (rootview.getTop() + rootview.getBottom());
                    // get the hypothenuse so the radius is from one corner to the other
                    int radius = (int) Math.hypot(right, bottom);
                    Animator reveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, cx, cy, 0, radius);
                    reveal.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    reveal.setDuration(350);
                    reveal.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                           // rootview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                        }
                    });
                    reveal.start();


                }
            });
```

->To Hide Reveal effect `onBackPressed()`

```
// previously visible view
            final View myView = findViewById(R.id.rootview);

            // get the center for the clipping circle
            int cx = myView.getWidth() / 2;
            int cy = myView.getHeight() / 2;

            // get the initial radius for the clipping circle
            float initialRadius = (float) Math.hypot(cx, cy);

            // create the animation (the final radius is zero)
            Animator anim =
                    ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, initialRadius, 0);
            anim.setDuration(50);
            // make the view invisible when the animation is done
            anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

            // start the animation
            anim.start();
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot man . Finally i got some solution. Can you tell me how to find Cx,Cy values for top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example animate the parent Layout of your activity. Here is an answer that might help you. It fades in the Activity but if you understand how its done you can apply any Animation.

[Fade In Android Launch Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012852/fade-in-android-launch-activity/29028065#29028065)

To cancel the standard built in Activity Animations you can use this [Intent.FLAG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION) :

```
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

when you start your Activity.